# How to map a package name to a different package name in a jar file

Tags: java

Suppose I have a jar foo-shaded.jar that contains the class `shaded.example.Foo`. Is it possible to create a mapping (perhaps in the MANIFEST.MF file) such that when the JVM tries to load `example.Foo` from foo-shaded.jar, `shaded.example.Foo` gets loaded instead?

Comment: No, it is not possible to do that.  You might achieve a similar effect with a custom `ClassLoader` that rewrote classes' bytecode at load time, but that would be tricky, messy, and open to all manner of interesting failure modes.

Comment: If you have some larger goal in mind, then perhaps we can suggest an alternative approach.

Comment: I have an alternative solution in mind; just wanted to know whether this approach was possible in Java. I guess not, and that's okay. Thanks for the confirmation!

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for the maven shade plugin?https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/